# how can solve : wp_enqueue_style was called incorrectly and script?

Tags: php, wordpress

how are you I have an issue when I login to the admin panel I face the following errors

Notice: wp_enqueue_style was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or login_enqueue_scripts hooks. This notice was triggered by the lity-style handle. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.3.0.) in /home/customer/www/remny.com/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5667

Notice: wp_enqueue_script was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or login_enqueue_scripts hooks. This notice was triggered by the lity-script handle. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.3.0.) in /home/customer/www/remny.com/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5667

let me know how can I fix

Answer (score 1):

In WordPress, you have to enqueue scripts and styles with corresponding function `wp_enqueue_script` and `wp_enqueue_style`. But, remember these functions should be only called after `wp_enqueue_scripts`, `admin_enqueue_scripts`, or `login_enqueue_scripts` hooks are triggered.

Those hooks are called in different scenarios.

1. `wp_enqueue_scripts` : This hook is triggered for frontend/public side of the WordPress.
2. `admin_enqueue_scripts`: This hook is only triggered for the admin side of the WordPress or you can say when the URL contains the `wp-admin`.
3. `login_enqueue_scripts`: It is a particular hook triggered only on the login page of WordPress which is usually accessed through http://example.com/wp-admin

An example is to enqueue scripts on the public side of the page.

```
/**
 * Enqueue a script with jQuery as a dependency.
 */
function wpdocs_scripts_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom_script.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_scripts_method' );
```

As you can see, the function `wp_enqueue_script` in only called after the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook is triggered.

Reference:

1. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/
2. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/

Comment: I'm new but where we wil put these triggered

Comment: can you help me?